# How to properly configure Grafana to work with mysql

Tags: mysql, grafana

Trying to configure Grafana 7.0.5 (running on Kubernetes) to use mysql instead of the default sqlite with partial success. Grafana does login to sql and creates the tables in the grafana db. But when I try to login I get the prompt and sometimes login fails, sometimes it is successful but then I either get kicked out with “unauthorized” (401 error code) or I get the login prompt again and nothing happens.

Any tips on how to properly configure this?

Below s a snippet of the relevant config.

```
[paths]
    data = /var/lib/grafana/data
    logs = /var/log/grafana
    plugins = /var/lib/grafana/plugins
    provisioning = /etc/grafana/provisioning
    [server]
    domain = localhost
    root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s/grafana
    serve_from_sub_path = true
    [security]
    ;allow_embedding = false
    ;cookie_samesite = lax
    ;cookie_secure = false
    admin_user = admin
    admin_password = admin
    [database]
    type = mysql
    host = mydb-host:3306
    name = grafana_db
    user = grafana
    password = grafanapasswd
```

Should the data and provisioning also point to the database on my sql host?

I've tried to change the cookie settings with "none" lax(default), etc but no success..

Comment: I was able to configure it to work but only with disable_login_form = true and [auth.anonymous]
    enabled = true
if I try with the login page, I get to enter the default credentials, and then I get the prompt to change the password or skip. When I click skip and I get the prompt again.
From the logs I see this:
t=2021-11-24T04:58:42+0000 lvl=info msg="Successful Login" logger=http.server User=admin@localhost
t=2021-11-24T04:58:45+0000 lvl=eror msg="Failed to look up user based on cookie" logger=context error="user token not found"

I cleared all cookies, same result.
I dont know